# How to use jasmine to test an async function that takes a long time to respond?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm using a function to fetch data from webapi. Basicly using `$.ajax`.

I'm now testing it with `waits()` like this:

```
describe('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function () {
  var r;
  it('fetchFilter', function () {
    runs(function () {
      model.fetch(opts)
      .done(function(data) {
        r = data;
      });
    });

    waits(2000);

    runs(function () {
      expect(r[0].gender).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is:

1. It's not guaranteed that `waits(2000)` will do the job well. Due to various reasons(network connections, algorithm efficiency of the api it self, etc.), I may have to `waits(5000)` or more, or for some models `waits(500)` is enough. And the most annoying thing is that it's all out of control.
2. A lot of `waits()` makes the test-specs-runs waste a lot of time waiting. The time of running the whole suite is too long to accept.

Is there some `best practice` of doing there kind of things?

PS: I know that unit test should not be applied to some function that relies on webapi or database. But I'm working with a single-page-js-heavy-webapp. The data fetching process is as important as how I will consume them with js models.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`waitsFor()` will wait for a specified latch callback to return `true` (it will try many time every few ms). It will also raise an exception if the specified timeout (5000ms in this case) is exceeded.

```
describe('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function () {
  var r, fetchDone;

  it('fetchFilter', function () {

    runs(function () {
      model.fetch(opts).done(function(data) {
        r = data;
        fetchDone = true;
      });
    });

    waitsFor(function() { 
      return fetchDone; 
    }, 5000); 

    runs(function () {
      expect(r[0].gender).toBeDefined();
    });

  });
});
```

Check the [Jasmine docs](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for more info on `waitsFor()` and `runs()`

Comment: When will the "failure message" be shown? The timeout prints the its own error message.

Comment: If you don't specify a failure message it will show a default timeout message. If you require a custom message you can use `waitsFor(function() {return fetchDone;}, "Timed out while waiting for fetch to be done, etc, etc.", 5000);`

Comment: `waitsFor` isn't available in jasmine2.

Comment: @Gurpreet nor is `waits`.

Comment: What if i have a problem when clicking into the login button, no action is executed can i make a specefic wait for jasmine framework, because right now no thing happens even the onclick effect isn't displayed?

Answer (score 2):

The following solution allows you to wait no more than really necessary but still you have to define max timeout you suppose to be enough. 
The `waitsFor` takes the function and waits until it returns `true` or the timeout passed as the last argument expired. Otherwise it fails.

Supposing the thing you need to wait for is that `r[0]` is defined at all, it could be:

```
waitsFor(
    function() { return r[0]; },
    'the data should be already set',
    5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

As per [jasmine 2.5](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Asynchronous_Support), you can pass an extra paramater for `it("scenario", callback, timeout)`

```
describe('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function (done) {
  var r, fetchDone;

  it('fetchFilter', function () {

    runs(function () {
      model.fetch(opts).done(function(data) {
        r = data;
        fetchDone = true;
      });
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        done();
    }, 9000); 

    runs(function () {
      expect(r[0].gender).toBeDefined();
    });

  });
},10000);
```