# Unit testing promises in AngularJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have this method that returns a promise and also makes use of other two promises internally:

```
this.getLocation = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var that = this;

    this.getCoords().then(function(coords) {
      var result = {};
      result.coords = coords;

      that.coordsToAddress(coords).success(function(address) {

        result.address = address;
        deferred.resolve(result);

      }).error(function() {
        deferred.reject('Unable to request coords to address');
      });
    }, function(reason) {
      deferred.reject(reason);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

As the two promises being called inside the function belong to a different module and have their own tests, I just want to test that `this.getCoords()` and `this.coordsToAddress()` were called.

I've setup my spies:

```
spyOn(Googlemaps, 'getCoords').andCallThrough();
spyOn(Googlemaps, 'coordsToAddress').andCallThrough();
```

And wrote this tests:

```
describe('getLocation()', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      Googlemaps.getLocation();
    });

    it('should call getCoords()', function() {
      expect(Googlemaps.getCoords).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should call coordsToAddress()', function() {
      expect(Googlemaps.coordsToAddress).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

The first one succeeds, while the last one fails:

```
Expected spy coordsToAddress to have been called.
```

My guess is that I need to fullfill the `getCoords()` promise in order for `coordsToAddress()` to be called. How can I do that? I tried triggering a digest with `$rootScope.$spply()` before checking that `coordsToAddress()` was called.

Comment: I'm on a phone so I can't give an exact answer. But if you use andCallFake() for the getCoords() spy instead of andCallThrough(), you can make the fake function (that you write) return a promise which you can then resolve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish here. If you really need to make the async call, you will need to investigate more about [Jasmine and async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315568/how-to-use-jasmine-to-test-an-async-function-that-takes-a-long-time-to-respond).

If you just want to verify the functions are being called, you could prevent the async call by using `.andReturn` to mock out the async call.

So the mocking would be something like this:

```
var coord = $q.defer().promise;
spyOn(Googlemaps, 'getCoords').andReturn(coord.resolve(yourMockCoords));

var toAdd = $q.defer().promise;
spyOn(Googlemaps, 'coordsToAddress').andReturn(toAdd.resolve(yourAddress));
```

This will allow you to no make any ajax calls and just verify that your calls are working correctly.