# How to mark a jasmine test as failed?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a jasmine 2.0 test that if a function is called, the test failed.

I have a function "Remote.get" that should call the first argument (which is a callback) if it is successful, or the second argument if it failed.

If it calls the second argument, I need to mark the test as failed.

How can I clearly mark the test as failed?

```
describe("my tests", function() {
  it("should call the first function", function(done) {          
    Remote.get(
      function() {
        // yeah! good!
        done();
      },
      function() {

        // whoa, if we got here, then it didn't work
        // fail()!

        done();
      }
    );             
  });
});
```

I know I could do something like `expect(true).toBe(false)` but I the error you get then would be unclear and unrelated to the actual problem. It should give an error like "wrong callback was called" or "Remote.get failure was called". I was hoping there was something more descriptive in Jasmine.

What I'm really looking for is the python equivalent of http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail.

Comment: You may have oversimplified; it's not clear to me what you are actually testing.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jasmine to test an async function that takes a long time to respond?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315568/how-to-use-jasmine-to-test-an-async-function-that-takes-a-long-time-to-respond)

Comment: You should follow the standard async pattern for Jasmine using `runs` and `waitsFor`. See the dupe I selected; give it a try and, if you still have issues, try to identify how your problem is different from that one.

Comment: Also, you should have at least 2 tests here: the first test to confirm that the success callback is fired, and the second to show that an error fires the error callback.

Comment: Yes, one would want to test all branches in the actual tests.

Comment: possibly kind of silly but you could do `expect('').toBe('wrong callback was called')` and you'd at least get that message showing up.  Still not quite equivalent to an outright `fail('message')` though.

Comment: another weird workaround would be to wrap your callback function `func` in a spy and then use `expect(func).not.toHaveBeenCalled()` .  still no custom failure message

Comment: Maybe i'm over-complicating things. Maybe i should just throw an exception there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write and register a [custom matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html) whose `compare` function in the return value always fails, and assign your custom message to the `message` property

Comment: I think this is the closest way to get a "fail" function in jasmine.

Answer (score 19):

They added a `fail()` method very recently in [this commit](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/commit/b1344d5c73c5e01a07e1ea435be3ed980f6db9de).  It will likely be released with the next point release of jasmine (assuming 2.1, unclear when this will be), or you can build your own from edge.

Comment: Hey @leech, this is the right answer to this question, simple and works perfectly, thanks @mmocny!